# Laravel v5.2.38 better error reporting than "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I think it's the most useless error message EVER.

> "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

Why can't it tell me what went wrong?

I already tried doing [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-the-hell-do-you-debug-properly-in-laravel?page=2) but it still won't give me an error message.

I also tried adding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) to the controller and view still nothing.

I also tried this in the `app.php`

```
'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'development'),
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),
```

I ended up doing `die` every line just to know what went wrong.

I checked the storage and no error logs just .gitignore

And what went wrong? Well, I was using an object variable as an array.

So why didn't it tell me that? But instead made me play a game of where's Waldo?

It does display helpful error messages "not always just like now"

Can anyone help me how to always display a helpful error message on Laravel?

Comment: Don't you have a laravel.log under the storage?
And below that message it usually say something about what was wrong.
Also you can see what was wrong looking into Console and see which script was faulty,
Anyway Laravel 5.5 have much more friendly error screens

Comment: @Radu nothing useful there just .gitignore

Comment: Try to make it yourself and see if it's logging something ...
I also edited my first comment.

Comment: @Radu I don't have CLI access on the hosted server so I can't do consoles. This time the error message was what I just posted nothing more.

Comment: Did you check `.env` file in project's root? Values there overwrite those in config/app.php. Especially check `APP_DEBUG` and `APP_LOG_LEVEL` entries in the file.

Comment: @magicianiam by console I mean the browser console .... 
like Inspect on Chrome and after that go to Console you can find there which scripts are giving error ad after click on it even the laravel error screen of course it's working especially on Ajax calls ....

Comment: Nothing on the console. Just that stupid error message of theirs inside HTML.

Comment: @Matey I'll go check that out.

Comment: Please keep us infomed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to show error messages in detail you need to have enabled the app-debug in your `.env` file:
`APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug`

---

Now the interesting part.

Add this to your `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` before the last `}`:

```php
/**
 * Create a Symfony response for the given exception.
 *
 * @param  \Exception  $e
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function convertExceptionToResponse(Exception $e)
{
    if (config('app.debug')) {
        $whoops = new \Whoops\Run;
        $whoops->pushHandler(new \Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler);

        return response()->make(
            $whoops->handleException($e),
            method_exists($e, 'getStatusCode') ? $e->getStatusCode() : 500,
            method_exists($e, 'getHeaders') ? $e->getHeaders() : []
        );
    }

    return parent::convertExceptionToResponse($e);
}
```

---

[Source](https://devmarketer.io/learn/prettier-helpful-error-pages-laravel-5-2-5-3/#code).

Comment: It seems it was the .env file that was being followed and not the one inside my config.